How can I filter google ads campaign data with date range filter?
As per my question, I want to filter the campaign's metrics based on the date range filter read the below code:
 /**
 * Runs the example.
 *
 * @param GoogleAdsClient $googleAdsClient the Google Ads API client
 * @param int $customerId the customer ID
 */
public static function getGoogleAdCampaigns(GoogleAdsClient $googleAdsClient, int $customerId)
{
    $googleAdsServiceClient = $googleAdsClient->getGoogleAdsServiceClient();
    // Creates a query that retrieves all campaigns.
    $query = "SELECT campaign.id, campaign.name,campaign.status, metrics.impressions, metrics.clicks, metrics.conversions, metrics.ctr, metrics.average_cpc, metrics.cost_micros, campaign.start_date, campaign.end_date FROM campaign WHERE campaign.status = 'ENABLED'";

    // Issues a search stream request.
    /** @var GoogleAdsServerStreamDecorator $stream */
    $stream = $googleAdsServiceClient->searchStream(
        SearchGoogleAdsStreamRequest::build($customerId, $query)
    );

    // Iterates over all rows in all messages and prints the requested field values for
    // the campaign in each row.
    // Initialize an array to hold campaign data
   $campaigns = [];

   // Iterates over all rows in all messages and collects the requested field values for
   // the campaign in each row.
   foreach ($stream->iterateAllElements() as $googleAdsRow) {
       /** @var GoogleAdsRow $googleAdsRow */
       $campaigns[] = [
           'id' => $googleAdsRow->getCampaign()->getId(),
           'name' => $googleAdsRow->getCampaign()->getName(),
           'start_date' => $googleAdsRow->getCampaign()->getStartDate(),
           'end_date' => $googleAdsRow->getCampaign()->getEndDate(),
           'status' => $googleAdsRow->getCampaign()->getStatus(),
           'impressions' => $googleAdsRow->getMetrics()->getImpressions(),
           'clicks' => $googleAdsRow->getMetrics()->getClicks(),
           'conversions' => $googleAdsRow->getMetrics()->getConversions(),
           'ctr' => $googleAdsRow->getMetrics()->getCtr(),
           'average_cpc' => $googleAdsRow->getMetrics()->getAverageCpc(),
           'cost_micros' => $googleAdsRow->getMetrics()->getCostMicros(),
       ];
   }
   // print_r($stream->iterateAllElements());
   // Return the collected campaign data array
    echo json_encode($campaigns);
    exit();
}

Suppose I want to get last week's clicks, impressions last week's cost, etc.
Reference : https://groups.google.com/g/adwords-api/c/H-6qp8v-k-o?pli=1

You need to add a segments.date into the select clause in your $query.
You then need to add an additional AND into your where clause (where segments.date BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-01-31')
